# How to draw infinitely long line in SCENEKIT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

I want to draw axes as that in SketchUp which are infinitely long. I already drew lines that are of fixed length but I want it infinitely long.

Comment: you can redraw the line as the screen moves or you can make that line stay in center

Comment: try to put 'INFINITY' as width or height from math.h

Comment: Didnt made it. Nice idea though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake it with fixed length lines that extend from beyond the camera's view (called the frustum), through it, and then beyond it again.

You can create beginning and ending `SCNNode` instances for each axis. Then every time the camera changes its view, call

```
func isNodeInsideFrustum(_ node: SCNNode,
     withPointOfView pointOfView: SCNNode) -> Bool
```

on each of your 6 endpoints. If an endpoint is within the frustum, move it farther out until it's not.

Methods in the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocol might be helpful to you.

Comment: Very very thank you. It will be more helpful if you show the implementation of the above function.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context of what you mean, you check for when the size of the line is about to cross some x or y axis in the screen. You can detect the size of the screen by using size.frame. Alternatively, you can use CGRectGetMidX, CGRectGetMidY, etc.

For example, I would do something like this:

```
var x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)
//Where y is the max size of the line you have
if x <= y {
    //Code where you make the line shape extend or add another line over it to make it look continous
}
```